# OrderBy then Select vs Select then OrderBy performance

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

I'm trying to figure out what should be done first: `OrderBy` or `Select`.
I have two options. Which one should I use? Or they are the same? (I'm on c# 12).

```cs
var opt1 = usersArr.OrderBy(u => u.Name).Select(u => u.Name).FirstOrDefault();

var opt2 = usersArr.Select(u => u.Name).OrderBy(u => u).FirstOrDefault();
```

PS: `users` is not ef `DbSet`. It's just an array

Comment: Select doesn't seem to have a place here. Probably you meant:
var name = usersArr.OrderBy(u => u.Name).FirstOrDefault().Name;

Comment: There is not much difference. Go for the better readable one.

Comment: I'd just run that into something like BenchmarkDotNet to be honest, get some hard numbers.

Comment: Instead of `.OrderBy(u => u)` you can use the newer `.Order()` which does the same thing and might be slightly faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sorting (`OrderBy`) we have to get all *items in memory*; that's why the second option can be faster: after `Select` we want less memory (just for `Name`, not for the entire item) to allocate which can be faster.

As **lidqy** mentioned in his answer, `MinBy` is a faster (`O(n)` vs. `O(n * log(n))`) and less memory consuming (`O(1)` vs. `O(n)`) option.
If you can't use `MinBy` (.Net 5 or lower), put `Aggregate`:

```
// I've used StringComparer.Ordinal comparer, but you may want to change it
var userWithFirstName = usersArr.Aggregate(
  (result, item) => StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare(result.Name, item.Name) <= 0 
    ? result 
    : item);
```

Comment: Well, all those "items" are references, assuming that user is a reference type, so it probably won't make a big difference in the end.

Answer (score 1):

opt2 could be slightly, not significantly, faster than opt1, because the property is accessed only once per item. The total count of iterations is however the same in both sequnces. So a benchmark would tell.

The fastest Linq-based solution is probably however (only available in .NET 6 and higher):

```
var userWithFirstName = usersArr.MinBy(u => u.Name);
```

Answer (score -1):

Personally I always go select then order. The reason for this is that if your using linq against sql, then your select statement will be grabbing less data in the sub query and then ordering. So it should be quicker. In your example I'm not sure if it's c# array or a linq to sql query.

usersArr > order > select would look something like:

```
SELECT t2.Name
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM users
    ORDER BY Name
) t2
```

Where as users > select would look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Name
    FROM users
) t2
ORDER BY Name
```

The first is more efficient in SQL. Now you may not be using Linq to SQL, but I always do first passes with SQL in mind (just natural to me now).

If you know your just using an array in memory (just C#) I can't imagine the order matters at all.

Comment: EF Core and other ORMs would translate both versions to a single-level query (no subquery). And the first version isn't valid SQL (you can't have an `ORDER BY` in a subquery without `TOP/LIMIT`) and even if it was valid it would be the same efficiency because SQL engines can optimize very well, transforming both of these into a single-level query